# Type error: 'int' object not callable - yes it is?

Tags: python

I'm trying to do an online course in computer programming and this is one of the first tasks to complete. I understand it so far, so I don't get it why the object Bucket is not callable when the code is pretty clear?

```
# [ ] show the type after assigning bucket = a whole number value such as 16 

bucket = (16)
type (bucket)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-57-a98943f63825> in <module>()
      1 # [ ] show the type after assigning bucket = a whole number value such as 16
      2 bucket = (16)
----> 3 type (buckets)

TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Why is this giving me issues? If anyone could explain this to me I would be very thankful.

Comment: Well, you most likely have an error in your code. If you want more details you will have to show us the code of the program, too.

Comment: Looks like you've assigned an integer value to a variable called ``type``, which overrides the built-in with the same name.

Answer (score -2):

Look at the name of the variable.

You created `bucket = (16)` but you called `type (buckets)`

`bucket` and `buckets` are different.

Comment: That does not explain the `TypeError`, this alone would raise a `NameError`

Comment: That TypeError occurs when the object that is called is not a function.

Comment: Yes I know, hence Martin's comments that they've likely shadowed `type` but you haven't answered the question here I'm afriad

Comment: This is definitely not the answer to the question